# Why doesn't EF Core automatically generate id field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm new to programming and development and I'm learning, and this is one of my learning projects. I've been trying to get around this in various ways, but when I try to add a new Vehicle Model to a specific Vehicle Make, the Id column doesn't automatically increment, but tries to overwrite the first Id.

I tried working around Data annotations, which I think are correct, I tried manually adding values to the database via queries, and it works perfectly. Tried deleting the db and migrations, changing the annotations again and nothing works. The only thing I can be doing wrong is the code itself, probably somewhere in the controller or service layer.

VehicleMake Class:

```
public class VehicleMake
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Make Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Abbreviation")]
        public string Abrv { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Models")]
        public virtual IEnumerable<VehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }
    }
```

VehicleModel Class:

```
public class VehicleModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int MakeId { get; set; }
        public virtual VehicleMake Make { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Model Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Abbreviation")]
        public string Abrv { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller for Vehicle Model:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(int Id, VehicleModel newModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                newModel.MakeId = Id;
                _model.Add(newModel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(newModel);
        }
```

Service for adding new model:

```
public void Add(VehicleModel newModel)
        {
            _context.Add(newModel);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here is the value it is trying to add to the db and of course gives an error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A842O.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on create you should not be passing an id, its should default to 0, also you should not pass the db entity/model as the viewModel, dont set the id baiscally and it will work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing an id to a create action in the first place? You should just have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(VehicleModel newModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(newModel);

        _context.Add(newModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Note:

1. I'm showing the minimal code here. If you want to factor out the call to `Add` and `SaveChangesAsync` to a service, that's fine.
2. Use the async methods when working with EF Core. ASP.NET Core and EF Core are both async all the way. The sync methods only exist for serving rare edge-case scenarios where you can't use async for some reason, and all they do is block on the async methods.

Comment: For the Id, I'm passing the make Id for the model here, as it doesn't recognize which Make I'm adding the model for.

As for the async methods, I will implement them, thank you for that.

Comment: You still don't need to do that. It's on your model. Bind to `MakeId` directly.